# Set placeholder text in Gtk.ComboBoxText?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, gtk, pygobject

I know how to set the default selection in a ComboBox, but I have a ComboBoxText widget that allows the user to enter his/her gender. So, I could use `Gtk.ComboBox.set_active()`, but that would express some sort of sexism, as the default selection would be either "Male" or "Female".

My question is how can I set a placeholder string on my ComboBox, but without it being in the list of choices?

Using python3 with gobject introspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the GtkComboBoxText with an entry, and then connect to the `format-entry-text` signal, and then return the default string if no other selection has been made. The Gtk+ docs contain an example of this signal (in C) here: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkComboBox.html#GtkComboBox-format-entry-text.

Comment: ComboBoxText is a ComboBox that displays text, not a ComboBoxEntry

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, to use this signal, you'll need to create it with an Entry. There's no other way to do what you want.

Comment: but IMO (off topic) I don't think having a default of "male" or "female" would indicate any sort of sexism

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding an 'unspecified' item to the combobox so yeah ;)